# Uncaught TypeError: Object function

Tags: javascript, php, chat, chatjs

I'm trying to implement ChatJS (chatjs.net) in web program. When I add all the scripts and and use this code:

```
  $.chat({
    // your user information
    user: {
        Id: 3,
        Name: 'John Silver',
        ProfilePictureUrl: 'http://www.foo.com/avatar/123'
    },
    // text displayed when the other user is typing
    typingText: ' is typing...',
    // the title for the user's list window
    titleText: 'ChatJS demo chat',
    // text displayed when there's no other users in the room
    emptyRoomText: "There's no one around here.",
    // the adapter you are using. There are 2 implementations out of the box:
    // SignalRAdapter and LongPollingAdapter (server independent).
    adapter: new LongPollingAdapter()
});
```

The web browser throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,n){return new x.fn.init(e,n,t)} has no method 'chat' localhost:8000/try2/:253 (anonymous function)
```

How can I fix this? If this can't be fixed easily, can someone recommend a similar open source program?

Comment: I think that means you have not succeeded in importing the script. The browser console should help determine what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: The script is being successfully imported, the browser only throws a single error.

Comment: That error means that `$.chat` does not exist.  How do you know that the script is being imported?

Comment: Oh, Ok, I  see it now, let me fix and try it.

Comment: Ok, So I have successfully loaded the JS. However, I'm trying to have a long polling adapter. I see that the script is trying to access /longpolling/getevents. I can't figure out what this is trying to do. The documentation is here: https://github.com/andrerpena/chatjs/wiki/Getting-up-and-running-with-long-polling. Do you understand what /longpolling/getevents is calling? What should I have at that page.

Comment: I think they're talking about interfacing with stuff you do on your server to implement the actual chat communications. I've never used that package however (or long polling, for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I rechecked my code, I realized that I forgot include a JS library. After I included it, it started working.